# activerecord search conditions - looking for null or false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When doing a search in active record I'm looking for record's that do not have an archived bit set to true.

Some of the archived bits are null (which are not archived) others have archived set to false.

Obviously,

```
Project.all(:conditions => {:archived => false})
```

misses the projects with the archived bits with null values.  How can all non-archived projects be selected wtih active record?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this (in Rails 2):

```
Project.all(:conditions => ['archived IS NULL OR archived = ?', false])
```

This is a limitation of older versions of Rails, as explained here: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1181-ar-find-producing-null-when-it-should-be-is-null

Comment: Ron - I get the following error message from SQLite when I do as you suggest. SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: FALSE: SELECT * FROM "review_phases" WHERE (closed IS NULL OR closed = FALSE) LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0 Could it be that SQLite just handles booleans differently making this not work?

Answer (score 96):

Rails 4 (possibly earlier) supports:

```
Project.where(archived: [false, nil])
```

... which is quite concise.

Comment: Works in Rails 3.2.14

Comment: also discovered this works (a bit off topic but another way to use null:

    Project.where(archived: valid_values + [nil])

such as...

   Project.where(linkage: account.project_codes.map(&:id) + [nil])

Answer (score 7):

The proper database agnostic way to do this is:

```
Project.where("archived IS NULL OR archived = ?", false)
```

Comment: Thanks! Works on both SQLite and Postgres. And just a note, if you think this isn't working, double-check that the values in your DB **are** false and not Null. Would've saved me some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

@metasoarous

Try:

```
Project.all(:conditions => "archived IS NULL OR archived = 'F'")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be database agnostic, you can do this in Rails 3:

```
Project.where("archived IS NULL OR archived = #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quoted_false}")
```

Comment: @SeanLazer's answer below works in Rails 3.0.9 and looks a bit cleaner.